# how to pass parameter in combobox(EXTJS) in javascript to php file?

Tags: php, javascript, extjs

First I declared an Ext.form.ComboBox which name is leventcombo and also I created a store Ext.data.JsonStore its name is leventstore. I can reach the php file  and  the data can return the javascript. But I cannot pass id value to the php file. how can I send it?

```
var leventcombo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    store: leventstore,// call jsonstore
    fieldLabel: '',
    minChars: 2,
    width:50,
    displayField:'isim',
    valueField: 'isim',
    typeAhead: false,
    loadingText: dil('Aranıyor...'),
    hideTrigger:true, 
    tpl: template1,
    emptyText: dil('levo ...'),
    itemSelector: 'div.search-item',
    name: 'leventwindeneme',
    id: 'leventwindenemeID',
    anchor: '100%',
    allowBlank:false,
    listeners:{
       beforequery: function(){
       }   
    }            
});


var leventstore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    totalProperty: 'results',
    root: 'rows',
    id: 'id',
    proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
       url: 'phps/leventstore.php?lang=dil(lang)'
    }),
    fields: [
    {
       ///phpden dönen veriler
       name:'id'
    },{
       ///phpden dönen veriler
       name:'isim'
    }]
});
```

leventstore.php:

```
<?php
include_once("kutuphane/inc.php");
$sql="select id, isim  from levent";
$_SESSION["VT"]->doQuery($sql);
$donecek = $_SESSION["VT"]->arrayYapVer();

$veriler=array();
if (sizeof($donecek) > 0) {
    foreach ($donecek as $file) {
        $tempFi = array();
        $tempFi = array(
            "id" => $file["id"],
            "isim" => $file["isim"]

        );
        array_push($veriler, $tempFi);
    }
}
$donecek = array("results" => (sizeof($donecek)), "success" => "true", "rows" => $veriler);
echo json_encode($donecek);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look here:
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Ajax-cfg-extraParams

You should use 'params' config option.

If you want to load store manually, use the following:

```
leventstore.proxy.extraParams.id = your_id;
leventstore.load();
```